# Errors converting form file to memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to upload a file and save into Azure Blob storage.
The file is injected as a FormFile.
The problem is that, there are errors when I convert the FormFile to a memory stream. The stream then uploads to Azure but with no data contained.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EndorsementId,FileName,ProviderId,Title")] Endorsement endorsement, IFormFile formFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
            var data = new MemoryStream();

            formFile.CopyTo(data);
            var buf = new byte[data.Length];
            data.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            UploadToAzure(data);

            ...
```

The errors are on the ReadTimeOut and WriteTimeOut properties of the memory stream. They say 'data.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' and 'data.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' respectively.

Here is how I injected the FormFile. There seems to be very little information on this.
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/uploading-files-with-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: ignoring results of Read/Write operations on streams is generally bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

`IFormFile` has `CopyToAsync` method for this purpose. You can just do something like below:

```
using (var outputStream = await blobReference.OpenWriteAsync())
{
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(outputStream, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The offset of the `MemoryStream` is still at the end of the file after you fill in the data.  You can either reset the position:

```
var data = new MemoryStream();

formFile.CopyTo(data);
// At this point, the Offset is at the end of the MemoryStream
// Either do this to seek to the beginning
data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var buf = new byte[data.Length];
data.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

UploadToAzure(data);
```

Or, rather than doing all of the work yourself, you can make `MemoryStream` just copy the data out for you to a `byte[]` array, by doing this after the `CopyTo()` call:

```
// Or, save yourself some work and just do this 
// to make MemoryStream do the work for you
UploadToAzure(data.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload content of IFormFile to Azure Blob Storage like this:

```cs
using (var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream())
{
    var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(azureBlobConnectionString);
    var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("filename");

    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
}
```